# windowsformのアプリをweb化したい

Tags: .net

windowsformでhttprequestを利用して外部サイトの更新を自動化するシステムのUIをweb化しようと考えています。
この場合プログラムを仮想化os(windowsが良いのか)で動作させるのが普通なのでしょうか？
現在.net4.5なので.net6に変更してlinuxにプログラムを配置するのが良いのか...
数十人使用する場合仮想化を数十個配置するのもイマイチだなと思いまして何か良い案あればご教授いただければありがたいです

#### 追記

他の同業他社がやっているので(大量のスクレイピング処理)当方もと考えております。
--逆にWebサーバーは自発的に動作することはありませんし、表示を行うこともできません
ブラウザ側でのUI面の対応は可能です。
問題はUIを分離したアプリをどこに配置するかの話になります。文面が分かりにくく申し訳ありません。

Comment: 「web化」とはどのような行為を想定されていますでしょうか？ 一般的なweb化とは異なることを想定されている可能性も危惧しています。また、xamlタグが指定されていましたがどのような意図でしょうか？ 少なくとも本文で一切触れられておらず無関係と思われるため削除しました。

Comment: 外部サイト更新用WinFormアプリのWeb化、アプリの仮想OS動作(VDI?)、Windows or .NET6.0&Linux配置、数十人使用で人数分仮想化といった風に見えるそれぞれのキーワードからまとまったイメージを組み立てにくい感じです。まだ説明されていない要求事項や要件がありそうで構想としても出来上がっていないのでは？ そういったモヤモヤとした内容では助言・回答は付きにくいと思われます。1つだけしか質問出来ないわけでは無いので、もっと切り分けてそれぞれ具体的な内容に変えて複数質問してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: windows server上でasp.netで開発したソフトを動かすのが、かんたんじゃないでしょうか？

Comment: 「大量のスクレイピング処理」ということはもしかして「外部サイトの更新を自動化する」のではなく「外部サイトが更新されたことの検出とその内容抽出を自動化する」ということではありませんか？ それだと質問内容が正確ではなく、他者に伝わっていない可能性が高いですね。課題/問題と質問内容を見直して修正するか新たに質問を立てることをお勧めします。

Answer (score 3):

考慮されていることが全くの的外れです。

WinFormsということは全ての処理はアプリケーション内で完結しているはずです。それをWeb化するということは、WebブラウザーとWebサーバーに分離されます。
Webブラウザーはセキュリティ上の制約がありWinFormsと同等の処理は行えません。その場合、Webサーバー上で実行することになります。逆にWebサーバーは自発的に動作することはありませんし、表示を行うこともできません。全てWebブラウザーからのリクエストで動作しますし、表示すべき内容は全てWebブラウザーに渡す必要があります。

この制約を踏まえて従来のアプリケーションの全ての機能に対し、Webブラウザー上で何を実行し、またWebサーバー上では何を実行するのかの判断を行い、更にWebブラウザー⇔Webサーバー間の通信内容を決定する。これらの設計を行う必要があります。

…といった検討項目がある中で、動作OSや.NETバージョンを尋ねる行為が適切だとは思えません。（すでに検討済みであればすみません。質問文からはそのようには読み取れませんでした。）

> 数十人使用する場合仮想化を数十個配置するのもイマイチ

Webサーバーの配置に関する見解だとしたら、一般的にはWebサーバーは１台に集約します。「数十人使用する」とのことで、Webサーバーではユーザー管理・セッション管理を行う必要が生じます。